Partial derivatives and functions
If I have $y=x^2$ and I have a function of $x$ and $y$ i.e. $f(x,y)=x+y$, then why is it that the partial derivative of this function with respect to $x$ is 1 whereas the partial derivative of $g(x)=x+x^2$ is $1+2x$, despite the fact that $f(x,y)=g(x)$?

Hint: the chain rule!

so their partial derivatives are equal in this case due to the chain rule? Also, in a case where f(x,y)=x+y and y isn't defined to be a function of x, why do we always assume that it is not a function of x?

Here, $y$ depends on $x$ already, so the chain rule says that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 1 + \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}.$$ But the latter derivative is $2x.$
As soon as you say a variable depends on another, the chain rule has to be used.
Compare this with $g(u, v) = u + v.$ If this is your whole function definition, where $u$ and $v$ do not depend on other variables (or one another!) then of course $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = 1.$$
The moral of the story: if we don't say that a variable depends on another, they're not related. If one variable depends on another, use the chain rule.
